# Search Substring in String collection

Tags: algorithms, strings, collections

I have a big collection of strings *a[1], …, a[N]* where *N* is about several millions. I am provided a string *m* and I need to iterate over all the strings *a[i]* that contain *m*. In other words, I need to find all the strings *a[i]* having *m* as substring.

What would be the most efficient data structure for that problem? I need to be very careful with memory as I am working with a big number of strings.

Comment: Is this related to specific programming language or is it acceptable to use databases?

Comment: you want a string searching algo? check [boyer-moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_moore) and variants

Comment: @MarekSebera database is acceptable

Answer (score 1):

if you skip `n` letters then you just need to check if the letter is in the first `n` of the input string and then check back again to see if it matches

this means creating a data structure (just a 256 long array with information about where the string might start) for the input string but allows the other collection of strings to remain unordered

also check out [this blog post](http://mailinator.blogspot.be/2008/01/how-to-search-for-word-pen1s-in-185.html), and the [boyer moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_moore)